# Java: How to Make certain JSON field not to be printed

Tags: java, json

I have a Document request that I need to send to a REST service endpoint:

```
@Data // lombok
public class Document {
    private String name;
    private String location; 
    private String content; // a base64 encoded byte array
}
```

I have a utility class that I can use to log the entire JSON object in the log file. So in case an exception is thrown at runtime, the code will log at the ERROR level the request that causes the exception, something like this:

```
{
     "name": "file1.pdf",
     "location" : "/root/folder/",
     "content" : "JVBERi0xLjQKJdP0zOEKJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

The problem is in the "content" field.  If the file is very large, the "content" field will fill up the log file very quickly when an exception happens at runtime.  So how do I make the "content" field not to be printed in the log file?  I thought about using `@JsonIgnore`, but will it make the "content" field to be ignored when the request is passed to the endpoint?  I am not using `Gson`.

Comment: "utility class that I can use to log" - what is this then?  You don't provide enough details.  Is this a class you wrote?

Comment: How do you log the exception?

Comment: @OldProgrammer  I updated the post with the logging method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JacksonMixin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations):

```
@Data
public class Document {
    private String name;
    private String location; 
    private String content;
}

public static abstract class ContentIgnoreMixin {
    @JsonIgnore
    private String content;
}

// same as ContentIgnoreMixin, but interface using getter
public interface class ContentIgnoreMixin2 {
    @JsonIgnore
    String getContent();
}
```

and later:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixIn(Document.class, ContentIgnoreMixin.class);  // or ContentIgnoreMixin2 - no difference 
    String jsonWithoutContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(objectWithContent);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Let me try that.

Comment: Also you can use interface with getters instead of abstract class with fields

Comment: yeah, I use lombok `@Data`